# Ajax Call Issue - 'faultcode:soapenv:Server'

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

I have create a button and written a logic to close a record when user click on that button. But when i'm clicking on the button it throw some exception like -

> A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was
>   encountered. {faultcode:'soapenv:Server', faultstring:'Dependent class
>   is invalid and need recompilation: Class Names......

Please help me on this.

Comment: Can you please add some code sample showing what you have done so far?

Comment: That sounds like the server-side code contains a compilation error. Click "Compile all classes" in the "Apex Classes" part of the "Setup" UI and fix the compilation errors.

Comment: Written a JS call "window.location.href="/apex/testPage?id=someid&action=closerecord" when i clisk on the button, getting error but when i simply paste the above url and pass the id it work properly.

Complete code :
   {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}
   {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")}
   window.location.href="/apex/testPage?id=someid&action=closerecord"

Comment: Any update friends?